# Erro Multiple object sets per type are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Estou com um erro em minha aplicação. Estou trabalhando com `Identity` para autenticação de usuários porem ao chamar o `Controller` criado é me retornado o seguinte erro:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Usuarios' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Projeto01.Areas.Seguranca.Models.Usuario'.

**Erro de origem:**

> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 33:             
>   Linha 34:             
>   Linha 35:                 @if (Model.Count() == 0)
>   Linha 36:                 {
>   Linha 37:

Porem não tem dois contextos de mesmo tipo, criei 2 um para a aplicação e outro para o `identity`.

```
   namespace Persistencia.Contexts
{
    public class EFContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFContext() 
            : base("EFContext") {
            Database.SetInitializer<EFContext>(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EFContext, Configuration>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(
            DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fabricante> Fabricantes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    }

}
```

e o outro:

```
 namespace Projeto01.DAL
{
    public class IdentityDbContextAplicacao : 
        IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public static object DataBase { get; private set; }

        public IdentityDbContextAplicacao() : base("IdentityDb")
        {}
        static IdentityDbContextAplicacao()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDbContextAplicacao>
                (new IdentityDbInit());
        }

        public static IdentityDbContextAplicacao Create()
        {
            return new IdentityDbContextAplicacao();
        }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    }
    public class IdentityDbInit: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
        <IdentityDbContextAplicacao>
    { }
}
```

View onde o erro ocorre:

```
 <tbody>
            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
                        Sem usuários registrados
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Alterar", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
                            |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

Alguem consegue enxergar alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que o  `IdentityDbContext` já seta o `DbSet` automaticamente e você está definindo ele novamente logo abaixo.

O seu contexto do Identity deveria ser assim

```
public class IdentityDbContextAplicacao : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
{
    public static object DataBase { get; private set; }

    public IdentityDbContextAplicacao() : base("IdentityDb") {}

    static IdentityDbContextAplicacao()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDbContextAplicacao>(new IdentityDbInit());
    }

    public static IdentityDbContextAplicacao Create()
    {
        return new IdentityDbContextAplicacao();
    }

    // Remova isto -> public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente ele está tentando criar o Usuário através dos 2 contextos. Você deve eliminar a criação dentro do arquivo gera pelo Migration.
Vá no migration da sua aplicação e no arquivo gerado quando você adiciona/atualiza um migration e tire as informações do "Usuário" dos métodos `Up` e `Down` (CreateTable, DropTable, etc) que funcionará.

Comment: No arquivo de criação do Migrations não tem nada relacionado a Usuarios, somente as minhas outras 3 tabelas, Produtos, Fabricantes e Categorias...

Comment: você poderia postar a classe onde o erro está acontecendo, então?

Comment: O erro ocorre na view Index, postei no topico inicial, o trecho em que é dado o erro..

Comment: Mas só a linha que gera o erro não ajuda muito. O interessante seria mostrar todo o contexto da sua chamada. Eu indicaria você postar toda sua view, o controller que chama a view, seu objeto tipado na tela também seria interessante. Se a aplicação roda, então o problema está em alguma lógica ou modelagem. A principio eu achei que o erro era na hora de tentar criar/atualizar o seu banco com o Fluent API.